# Virtualbox на MacOS: не доступны 64-битные ОС

Tags: virtualbox

Хостовая машина MacBook на процессоре М1. После установки `Virtualbox` и `Extension Pack` заметил, что нет поддержки виртуализации x64.

Как решить?

Comment: Скорее всего никак, вряд ли ARM-процессор способен виртуализировать x86/x64 архитектуру

Comment: Да вот на те-же новости натыкаюсь...